# Can I connect 54v DC 3.15A Power adapter to a 48-54v DC 1.5-2.6A Device?

Tags: switch

I have a `AC <-> DC` converter that outputs `54v DC` at `3.15A`.

Can I connect this to a device that has the input specification `48-54v DC` and `1.5-2.6A` ?

Will the device get damaged or will it work fine?

Comment: AFAIK it should work.

Comment: 1) What computer equipment are you talking about?  2) It isn't clear why the device power requirement would be expressed as a broad range.  What determines the requirement?  3) Does it have the right connector and the right polarity?  4) If the only issue is the converter current output, that is a maximum capacity; the connected device will only draw what it needs.

Comment: Note that advice you get here is going to assume that the converter has a well regulated output, intended for electronic devices.  If it is something like a dedicated power pack for a motorized device, it may have minimal voltage regulation, assuming it will be used with the load of the intended device.  Using something like that at half its designed output current, the output voltage could potentially be higher, which could put it dangerously above the maximum input voltage of your device.  Provide more details in the question so that answers are not unintentionally misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can; the device will work fine. The Voltage is within limits (both devices support 54V) and the provided current is higher that the required one (drawn by the device). 3.15A can certainly feed a device draining up to 2.6A.

Technically, you're 100% fine, just make sure the polarity is correct.